# How do I wrap an empty submenu?

Tags: menu, typo3

I have this menu in TYPO3:

```
HEADER = HMENU
HEADER {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <ul class="select one"><li>|</li></ul> || <ul class="select two"><li>|</li></ul>
    }
    ACT < .NO
    ACT = 1
    ACT {
      wrapItemAndSub = <ul class="current one"><li>|</li></ul> || <ul class="current two"><li>|</li></ul>
    }
  }
  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul class="sub">|</ul>
  2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current_sub">|</li>
}
```

Here is the resulting HTML code:

```
<ul class="current one">
    <li>
        <a href="/index.html">Homepage</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="/index/subpage.html">Subpage</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="current two">
    <li>
        <a href="/secondpage.html">Second page</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, there are no subpages below the second page. That is the reason `<ul class="sub">...</ul>` is **not** rendered for second page.

However, I need the `<ul class="sub"></ul>` - even if there is nothing in it.

How can I get it into my code?

Answer (score 0):

Premise: the whole menu seems a bit...odd... at least for my tastes (each first level item is wrapped with an `<ul>`, and you also require an additional empty `<ul>` even without subitems...)

Said that, this trick should work: Basically I appended at the NO state a "fake" empty `<ul class="sub"></ul>` and I removed it when the actual subpages kick in.

```
  HEADER = HMENU
  HEADER{
    
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <ul class="select one"><li>|</li></ul> || <ul class="select two"><li>|</li></ul>
    }
    
    NO.after =  <ul class="sub"></ul>
    ACT < .NO
    ACT = 1
    ACT {
      wrapItemAndSub = <ul class="current one"><li>|</li></ul> || <ul class="current two"><li>|</li></ul>
    }
   IFSUB < .NO 
   IFSUB = 1
   IFSUB.after =  
   
   ACTIFSUB < .ACT
   ACTIFSUB = 1
   ACTIFSUB.after =  
  }

  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul class="sub">|</ul>
  2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
  2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current_sub">|</li>    
  
  }
```

Comment: That set me on the right track! I still had to do some additions for certain cases, but my solution is based on your idea. I'll post below what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up using. I still took care to remove the additional code again for the second level and I made sure the right classes still are applied on level 2:

```
    HEADER = HMENU
    HEADER {
      1 = TMENU
      1 {
        expAll = 1
        NO = 1
        NO {
          wrapItemAndSub = <ul class="select one"><li>|</li></ul> || <ul class="select two"><li>|</li></ul>
        }
        NO.after = <ul class="sub"><li class="empty">&nbsp;</li></ul>
    
        ACT < .NO
        ACT = 1
        ACT {
          wrapItemAndSub = <ul class="current one"><li>|</li></ul> || <ul class="current two"><li>|</li></ul>
        }
    
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB.after = 
    
        ACTIFSUB < .ACT
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB.after = 
      }
    
      2 < .1
      2.wrap = <ul class="sub">|</ul>
    
      2.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      2.NO.after = 
    
      2.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current_sub">|</li>
      2.ACT.after = 
    
      2.IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    
      2.ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current_sub">|</li>
    }
```